# Installing R from cmd

Tags: r, cmd

Can I configure the R installation from Windows cmd?

```
C:\R-3.3.1-win.exe /silent
```

Gives me a standard silent install, but:

```
C:\R-3.3.1-win.exe /help
```

gives me no information. Also /? says nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution, first determine the configurations for the installer:

```
C:\R-3.3.1-win.exe /SAVEINF=config
```

This will save those configurations in a file named config. To load those configurations on the installer use:

```
R-3.3.2-win.exe /SILENT /LOADINF=config
```